# Spring Rest docs custom snippets are ignored

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, documentation, spring-restdocs

Setup:

Intellij IDE community

Spring Boot 2.4.0

Spring rest docs

Hi,
I use spring rest docs in all my services. The problem is that in one of them, the custom snippets are ignored and I just don't know why. Although if i'm sure that it's a mistake of mine I just can't find it.

**Example snippet**

One of the snippets I want to customize is the http request.
So I placed a file `http-request.snippet` under `src/test/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates/asciidoctor`

Content:

```
[source,http,options="nowrap"]
----
{{method}} {{path}} HTTP/1.1
----
```

[image]

So I would expect that the requestbody is not documented in this snippet but instead it is still included.

Like I said all my snippets are ignored.

**UPDATE:**
I've debugged `StandardTemplateResourceResolver class.` In fact, my templates are ignored.

[image]

I looked at the path and as you can see the method `getFormatSpecificCustomTemplate` should resolve my snippets but it doesn't.

[image]

Is there something else I have to configure when I add a new resource folder and I add it to the classpath?

**SOLVED**
I found the problem by looking at the asciidoc path in my explorer. The problem was that the creation of the direktories went wrong. Instead of creatin nested subdirectories for `org/springframework/..` there was one folder with the whole directory structure as one name. Sorry for the confusion but in intellij the structure looked right.

Comment: The snippet template resolution is performed by `StandardTemplateResourceResolver`. Perhaps using the debugger with a breakpoint on that class's `resolveTemplateResource` method will help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks for the hint. I updated my question.